# Problema para convertir un componente de clase a un componente funcional

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-hooks, component

Tengo este codigo de mi clase principal donde estoy obteniendo un token, quisiera poder convertir esta componente clase a un componente funcional, estuve intentando pero tenia errores a la hora hacer los estados

> ```
> import React from "react";
> import {Login} from "./login";
>
> class Logapp extends React.Component {
>   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {
>       body: {}
>     };
>   }
>   componentDidMount() {
>     fetch(`http://localhost:3011/user`, { credentials: 'include' 
>     })
>       .then(response => response.json())
>       .then(response => this.setState(
>         {
>           body: response
>         })
>       );
>   }
>   render() {
>     return (
>         <Login body={this.state.body} uri={`http://localhost:3011`}/>  
>     );
>   }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir ese componente de clase en uno funcional sería así. Como consejo, te sugiero que cuando realices una pregunta, adjuntes también el código que intentaste implementar para el componente funcional y/o el error que estás recibiendo. Así también puedes recibir feedback al respecto y saber dónde estás fallando.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Login } from './login'

const Logapp = (props) => {
  const [body, setBody] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3011/user`, { credentials: 'include' })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => setBody(response))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [])
  return <Login body={body} uri={`http://localhost:3011`} />
}

export default Logapp
```

Comment: genial amigo , pero ahora salio un problemilla que cuando recupero los datos me recupera en un promise y con el anterior codigo me recuperaba un body que tenia un token dentro.

Comment: @LiAbelCarlosLopinta acabo de editar el snippet. Intenta con el nuevo.

Comment: @AmilcatMunoz Gracias si me funciono.